# Alternatives to Unity for netbooks?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

I am very disappointed with some of the features of Unity. Not being able to hide the bar or even modify it with different shortcuts (favorites in 10.04 netbook remix). I have docky installed and I would prefer to just use that. But I want to still have the system administration programs somehow. What packages would anyone recommend as a replacement for Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2D netbook interface from 10.04 is still there.  You can use it if you install [`ubuntu-netbook-efl-default-settings`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-netbook-efl-default-settings) & [`netbook-launcher-efl`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/netbook-launcher-efl) (click the package names to install them, after installation there will be a new session choice in the login screen).

I don't understand why Docky would prevent you from running system administration programs?

Answer (score 1):

In the background of docky I recommend you just run GNOME to give you access to all your sys admin tools.

Answer (score 1):

xubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

I would say give KDE's netbook interface a try. I was very impressed with it compared to Unity.